# Book set in modern times about a woman who meets a man who turns out to be a wyvern

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

I read this book as a child so I’m sorry for how little I can remember.

This was a novel about a woman who meets a man who turns out to be a wyvern. They’re categorized by color and he’s a black wyvern; there’re also green wyverns and red ones, as far as I recall. She isn’t human and is slowly learning how to be a mage, I think, or some kind of witch. There’s a big disagreement at the end, which leads to the main male protagonist revealing that he’s actually a white wyvern, not a black one. It was also set in modern times and they lived in a city.

Please help! It’s been killing me to try to find it all week.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: Sounds kind of like Katie Macalister's Aisling Gray series & sequels, but they aren't kids books.